# What packages do I need to install in R to perform Hotelling T^2 test

Tags: r

I tried to install package ICSNP but it is not available for R 4.1.3 version.
I tried to change the directory to ICSNP using  cd ICSNP  and I got the following error message Error: unexpected symbol in "cd ICSNP"
I also tried to use  setwd("ICSNP ") as well. and I got the following error message
Error in setwd("ICSNP") : cannot change working directory
so I could not install  the ICSNP package to perform the Hotelling T test

I tried the following
devtools::install_github("klausnordhausen/ICSNP")
it also give me an error message

Comment: If you use RStudio/Posit, just install it via packages --> Install --> ICSNP. I can't image, the R-version causes an error.

Comment: Please don't ask SO users community to google for you, the first hit to **hotelling's t2 test in r**  was this package: `install.packages("DescTools")`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is asking SO users community to google for them, the first hit to "hotelling's t2 test in r" was a relevant R package.

Comment: I may ask some basics questions because I am still learning R. 
I tried to download ICSNP via packages --> Install --> ICSNP and I got this error
Error: package ‘mvtnorm’ required by ‘ICSNP’ could not be found. 
Moreover ,package ‘mvtnorm  is not available via packages.